# dynamic ionic icon with react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, array.prototype.map

I want to make my IonIcons dynamic so they are reusable. But i need to set it in {} I dont know how i do this with a .map() element.

```
import React from "react";
import { IonIcon, IonLabel } from "@ionic/react";
import styles from "./quickOptions.module.css";
import { alarmOutline, personOutline, cartOutline } from "ionicons/icons";

export default function quichOptions() {
  const quickOptions = [
    { title: "Jouw consulent", icon: { personOutline } },
    { title: "Jouw afspraken", icon: { alarmOutline } },
    { title: "Jouw bestellingen", icon: { cartOutline } },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      {quickOptions?.map((element: any) => {
        return (
          <div key={element.title} className={styles.btnContainer}>
            <IonLabel>{element.title}</IonLabel>
            <IonIcon icon={element.icon} size="large" /> //here
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Element.icon does not give the output of {personOutline} for example does anybody know how to fix this??

Comment: your icon key must have string value. e.g `icon: 'icon-name-outline'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check console.log(typeof element.icon)

> const quickOptions = [
> { title: "Jouw consulent", icon: 'personOutline'  },
> ];

```
<IonIcon icon={element.icon} size="large" />
```

if the icon type here is {string}, that's why it doesn't work 
try it in quickOptions ,  icon: personOutline or icon: 'personOutline'

Comment: Yea i see it. Stupid mistake from me.